# Powershell Script not working out of ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a powershell Script that runs fine in the ISE, but when I run it directly from the .ps1 file it stops at this point:

```
Write-Host "Attempting to start FFMPEG Process with arguments:$ArgumentList::::" -ForegroundColor Green
Start-Process $SCRIPT:FFMPEGLocation $ArgumentList -Wait
```

I get the `Write-Host` printout, with the correct Argument List, but no window pops up for the start-process or anything.  I made sure to use the SCRIPT scope variable for anything that is outside the function.  It runs fine in ISE just not when I run it in Console.  No errors either, and the `$SCRIPT:FFMPEGLocation` variable is a direct path to the exe to be executed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need more let me know.

```
PSVersion               5.1.14393.1066   
OSVersion               10.0.14393
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `script` scope for the path and filename of the executable? Why `Start-Process`? In fact, why do you need script at all? Just run the executable from the PowerShell prompt with the parameters you want.

Comment: Thank you Bill!  My current script is over 200 lines long, and I realized halfway through that I should have instead coded in C# instead, but I was rolling along too much.  I have certain variables, like `$SCRIPT:FFMPEGLocation` declared at the top of my script outside of a `try {` section.  I know, I was a bad boy and am trying to do too much in a scripting language.  I'm just trying to make this work outside of the ISE for now, and then I can make a program or service in C# later.

Comment: Running commands works just fine from PowerShell whether in the ISE or not. You have not included nearly enough information in your question. (If I had to guess, you have a scoping problem.)

Comment: Yes, Bill.  You are correct, I have not included enough info.  And it probably is a scoping problem, among many other problems that I have, which is why I was using the SCRIPT Scope for anything that wasn't declared and set in the same block.  the output shows everything correct in the console which is why I am stumped with the scope.  But i shall trudge along.

Comment: I recommend starting small and writing a very short script that contains only the absolute minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. This is often referred to as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @DrewCourtney Include `$($script:FFMPEGLocation)` in the `Write-Host` to ensure it contains what you expect. You have already confirmed that `$ArgumentList` is as expected.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart ... [or MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @gms0ulman - yes, exactly.

Comment: It is indeed a scope issue, I thought that by specifying $SCRIPT:FFPMEGLocation in a ReadConfig function, then I would be able to read that variable anywhere in the script outside that function.  I can see the variable in the main body of the script, but in my file system watch even it is no longer available.  In fact, several other variables I thought would be there aren't.  Thank you Bill!  Chaning it to a GLOBAL scope makes it work.  I was hoping to get away from GLOBAL,

Comment: @Bill_Stewart if you submit your response regarding scope as an AnswerI will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Actually, it was @gms0ulman that got me really going, if you submit your suggestion to add that variable to my write-host I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @DrewCourtney Glad to hear it's sorted! I also try to avoid global scope as it's easy to overuse and generally bad practice; moved to using `return` to pass required values around, and attempting to rethink the logic before resorting to global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, check the value passed to `Start-Process` to ensure it contains what you expect as the issue is likely to be with `$SCRIPT:FFMPEGLocation`.

The difference between the ISE and Console with regard to scope can be frustrating.
See [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/777416/why-does-the-powershell-ise-not-isolate-script-variables-to-the-script-scope) which explains the behaviour further
. You may also find [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/631198/how-can-i-automatically-clean-up-script-scoped-variables-in-powershell-ise) helpful;
 [BartekB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674943/bartekb) explains that `F5` in the ISE actually [dot-sources](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html) the script instead of [calling](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) it, and provides a function to run a clean session.

Comment: On the nose!  I added the variable to my write-host and viola, I had a scope issue!  Set the variable to $GLOBAL: and that fixed it, as well as several smaller issues I had been having.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method which will also wait on the process that needs to be run:

```
& $EXE /arg 1 /arg 2 -etc 2>&1 | % { $_ }
```

This will execute the command and pass the args, redirect any errors to the output stream and then print that output (for some reason, I've had bad luck with actually getting output from commands)

Comment: I just could never get that to work with such a long argument list.  Could I do something like: `& $SCRIPT:FFMPEGLocation $ArgumentList 2>&1 | % { $_ }` to pass a really long argument list?

Comment: Sometimes PS is a little weird about commands & arguments.  I'd suggest reading [this article](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/)

Comment: Awesome @TheInforrigible1 I found that article a week ago but couldn't find it again.  I printed that out, and am referencing that.  Thank you!